# R script for calculating pooled prevalence

Tags: rscript, meta-analysis

I was wondering whether anyone could advise on how to calculate pooled prevalence, using percentages from studies?  I have found meta-analyses that have done this but cannot find any information on how to actually calculate this.
Please can you advise on what the R script would look like for this? Thanks for your help.

I have searched online for advice and I would like some clarity around using percentages, as a lot of the information discusses pooled proportions and transforming this or pooled effect sizes.